# Sharedpreferences retrieve String

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I save some EditText data into shared preferences and then on another activity I show it in TextView (it works - easy) - but when I want to use saved variable in a method it does not work - do you have any idea how to retrieve e.g. IP from shared pref?

```
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String AJPI  = Text1.getText().toString();
editor.putString(IPv4, AJPI);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: check demo http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this line?

```
editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
.edit()
.putString(IPv4, "myString").apply();
```

Retrieve:

```
String s =
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
.getString("myString", "defaultStringIfNothingFound");
```

Comment: It works for showing the string on the layout/Activity but it is not working for using the variable String in the method...

Comment: is this `IPv4` variable you want to save into `Sharedpreferences`  or this `AJPI` ? because as I can see in your code you are not saving the `editText` variable in `Preferences`. So it should be like this: `.putString(AJPI, "myString").apply();`

Answer (score 0):

Save to SharePreference

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.putString("Value", your_value);
 editor.commit();
```

Read from SharePreference

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String phone_number = pref .getString("Value", "");
```